# Swift UserDefaults prior data entry

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Is there any way to populate UserDefaults with data before running the app so something can be added to it during runtime. For example say I want "Apples", "Bananas" and "Carrots" to be added manually prior to the application running in UserDefaults for use whenever, but then want to add "Dill" and "Eggplant" so the next time the application runs all A, B, C, D and E are available in the UserDefaults

```
struct MyVariables
{
    let ArrayList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "ArrayList")
}
```

Comment: [**Register**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) default values.

Answer (score 1):

UserDefaults has a class method `register(defaults:)` that you can use to register a dictionary of "default defaults". Take a look at the docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create singleton DataManager and create custom init method. In this init you can specify, how the table should be populated, when the data should be added/removed.